# Require.js with jquerymobile in worklight for developing cross platform hybrid app

Tags: jquery-mobile, requirejs, ibm-mobilefirst

For page load performance and managing scripts dependency I would like to use require.js with jquerymobile in Worklight hybrid app.

Does Worklight supports this style of code (require.js + JQM ) for building cross platform app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQM, Dojo, Sencha, HTML5, PhoneGap etc.

@Nick, Worklight isn't built on top of PhoneGap, they have been using PhoneGap as a run time API, they embedded the Cordova into IBM Worklight.

Check out the Worklight Client Architeture at http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/features/phonegap/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that styling of coding / devlopment should be supported.

When I first started toying around with Worklight, I used AMD and Dojo to build a little test app. You should remember that Worklight is built on top of Apache Cordova and has many of the same capabilities and restrictions as Cordova. Worklight adds alot of extra features on top of it but at its base that's what it's using.